# Open id get username after successful authentication

Tags: openid

I am using openid using openid4java. My return url is a servlet

After authentication when the return url is invoked by the openid provider after successfully authentication  , i want the **USERNAME** from the open id url like
https://me.yahoo.com/**USERNAME**

the above url i am recieving from parameter openid.identity i cannot get username directly since user is entering user name on the openid provider site.

Please give any suggestion
 Regards, Zeeshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure this is what you're asking, but if you want Yahoo to pass you a nickname or an email address for the user, you can add the Attribute Exchange extension to your OpenID request.

- [Y!'s blog post announcing AX support](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2009/12/yahoo_openid_now_with_attribute_exchange.html)
- [a later post with an updated list of supported attributes](http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?s=&showtopic=4279&view=findpost&p=13768)

Comment: Hi keturn , i was able to get email of providers except yahoo, with your information i was able to retrieve email of yahoo also, 
Thanks